# Xamarin Httpclient unreliable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin.Forms app that makes recurring calls (every 15 seconds) to a page on a website and passing authentication details. (Https if that makes a difference)

During testing, I noticed occasionally the app would time out, but not enough to cause any major concern.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

The app has now been deployed on various tablets which are with clients, many of which are reporting connectivity issues. If the call failed 20 times in a row (so after 5 minutes of no response) it will alert the user, this is happening regularly, restarting the app sometimes appears to fix this, but often not.

I can confirm that all the tablets have a stable internet connection, and is able to browse the internet with no issues.

I have a timeout of 25 seconds, which is of course very long (And perhaps may be causing some issues as it can hang longer than until the next call is made?)

I am using ModernHttpClient ( https://github.com/Ideine/ModernHttpClient ) on version 3.0.2

Please consider the following code:

```
    public static HttpClient cl = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cl.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
    }


    public static async Task<OrderResponse> GetOrdersREST(FormUrlEncodedContent payload)
    {
        var request = await cl.PostAsync((RESTURL + "/getrestaurantorders.php"), payload);
        var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        OrderResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderResponse>(response);
        return res;
    }


    var formcontentx = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("establishment_id",establishment_id),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("token",token),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("alternate_restaurant_id",alternate),
    });

    // Attempt to send the payload and receive a LoginResponse object from the website
    try
    {
        var responder = await App.GetOrdersREST(formcontentx);
        if (responder.message != "INVALID_TOKEN")
        {
            if (troubleConnecting > 20)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Reconnected", "You have successfully been reconnected to the website.", "Ok");
            }
            // Do whatever needs to be done with info
        }
        else
        {
            // Uninteresting error handling
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        troubleConnecting++;
        if (troubleConnecting == 20)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Unable to connect", "Unfortunately we are having trouble connecting you to the website.", "Ok");
        }
    }
```

Any assistance, advise or extra info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I am just adding Polly in now